# Extracting function from contour plot

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, 3d

I have made a contour plot via `Minitab` and got an image like this one:

[image: contour plot]

With

- $z$ being the enthalpy $[BTU/lb]$
- $x$ being the temperature $[°F]$
- $y$ being the concentration [%]

How can I mathematically access its function $z = f(x,y)$ from just the data behind the picture?
Is there a possibility to get $z = f(x,y)$ from this via programming/software?

***EDIT:***

**Part of my data:**

| x = Concentration [%] | y = Temperature [°F] | z = Enthalpy [BTU / lb] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 32 | 4 |
| 5 | 32 | -16 |
| 10 | 32 | -32 |
| 15 | 32 | -48 |
| 20 | 32 | -63 |
| 25 | 32 | -76 |
| 30 | 32 | -90 |
| 35 | 32 | -103 |
| 40 | 32 | -116 |
| 45 | 32 | -124 |
| 50 | 32 | -128 |
| 55 | 32 | -132 |
| 60 | 32 | -136 |
| 65 | 32 | -139 |
| 70 | 32 | -136 |
| 75 | 32 | -128 |
| 80 | 32 | -118 |
| 85 | 32 | -100 |
| 90 | 32 | -75 |
| 95 | 32 | -40 |
| 100 | 32 | 2 |
| 0 | 50 | 16 |
| 5 | 50 | 0 |
| 10 | 50 | -18 |
| 15 | 50 | -32 |
| 20 | 50 | -48 |
| 25 | 50 | -63 |
| 30 | 50 | -78 |
| 35 | 50 | -90 |
| 40 | 50 | -100 |
| 45 | 50 | -111 |
| 50 | 50 | -118 |
| 55 | 50 | -123 |
| 60 | 50 | -125 |
| 65 | 50 | -128 |
| 70 | 50 | -125 |
| 75 | 50 | -121 |
| 80 | 50 | -112 |
| 85 | 50 | -96 |
| 90 | 50 | -70 |
| 95 | 50 | -37 |
| 100 | 50 | 4 |

*Picture:*

[image: nomogram]

@Claude:

- BTU/lb_5 = - 48,72 + 1,007 Temp - 0,000163 Temp^2
- BTU/lb_10 = - 65,25 + 1,001 Temp - 0,000287 Temp^2
- BTU/lb_15 = - 77,55 + 0,9209 Temp - 0,000163 Temp^2
- BTU/lb_20 = - 90,01 + 0,8385 Temp + 0,000043 Temp^2
- BTU/lb_25 = - 100,7 + 0,7528 Temp + 0,000226 Temp^2

Comment: I suppose that you generated the plot from a formula $f(x,y,z)$. What is it ?

Comment: I have added part of the data I used. I am looking for a way to describe a formula with this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follows a MATHEMATICA script that I hope, will express with sufficient accuracy, the formulation needed $z = f(x,y)$

```
data1 = {{5, -48.72}, {10, -65.25}, {15, -77.55}, {20, -90.01}, {25,-100.7}};
data2 = {{5, 1.007}, {10, 1.001}, {15, 0.9209}, {20, 0.8385}, {25, 0.7528}};
data3 = {{5, -0.000163}, {10, -0.000287}, {15, -0.000163}, {20, 0.000043}, {25, 0.000226}};

fc1 = c10 + c11 w + c12 w^2 + c13 w^3 + c14 w^4;
fc2 = c20 + c21 w + c22 w^2 + c23 w^3 + c24 w^4;
fc3 = c30 + c31 w + c32 w^2 + c33 w^3 + c34 w^4;

c0 = NonlinearModelFit[data1, fc1, {c10, c11, c12, c13, c14}, w];
c1 = NonlinearModelFit[data2, fc2, {c20, c21, c22, c23, c24}, w];
c2 = NonlinearModelFit[data3, fc3, {c30, c31, c32, c33, c34}, w];

f[Temp_, w_] := -(c0[w] + c1[w] Temp + c2[w] Temp^2)

ContourPlot[f[Temp, w], {w, 5, 25}, {Temp, 0, 100}, Contours -> 15, ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{f[Temp, 15], f[Temp, 17], f[Temp, 20]}, {Temp, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Added a python script to define $z = f(x,y)$

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def coefs(w,c0,c1,c2,c3,c4):
    return c0 + c1*w + c2*w ** 2 + c3*w ** 3 + c4*w ** 4

x_values  = [5., 10., 15., 20., 25.]
c0_values = [48.72, 65.25, 77.55, 90.01, 100.7]
c1_values = [-1.007, -1.001, -0.9209, -0.8385, -0.7528]
c2_values = [0.000163, 0.000287, 0.000163, -0.000043, -0.000226]

coefsc0, _ = curve_fit(coefs, x_values, c0_values)
coefsc1, _ = curve_fit(coefs, x_values, c1_values)
coefsc2, _ = curve_fit(coefs, x_values, c2_values)


def C(p, x):
    val = 0
    for i, pp in enumerate(p):
        val += pp * x**i
    return val


def f(t,w):
    return C(coefsc0,w) + (C(coefsc1,w) + C(coefsc2,w)*t)*t

print(f(0,15))
```

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce this via VBA or some freeware?
For my understanding:
You created three arrays with (x,y) = Data1-3;
You created three relations fc1-3 with quartic constants, with `w`being?;
You created three "models" c0-2 with the parameters meaning what?
Then you made a function f[temp] with "minus" the function of Claude, why "minus"?

Comment: I will prepare a python version Asap.

Comment: @Capt.Krusty A python script was included.

Comment: Thanks for your update

Answer (score 1):

Being myself thermodynamicist, I think you should consider the enthalpy as a function of temeperature for a given concentration because it must be a smooth function, probably well approximated by a quadratic polynomial for any concentration.

So, let us suppose that for a given  concentration $y$ we have
$$z_y =a_y+b_y\, x + c_y\, x^2$$ the three coefficients are easy to obtain. Now, look how each of them varies with $y$. Suppose that the first one is linear, the second cubic and the third quadratic. In such a case, the model would be
$$z=(a_0+a_1\,y)+(b_0+b_1\,y+b_2\,y^2 +b_3\,y^3)x+(c_0+c_1\,y+c_2\,y^2 )x^2$$ Now, use all the data and refit the parameters (it is just a linear regression).

Comment: I just created the coefficients ($a_0$ - $c_2$) and made in excel a `Solver` solution by minimizing the sum of errors. This resulted in values differentiating by 1E+14 average.
Can you give me a further example, looks like I am missing something.

Comment: Add the plot of $(a_y,b_y,c_y)$ as function of $y$. Was the fit of $z_y$ good or not ?

Comment: For the whole dataset at $32°F$ the fit was $BTU/lb$ (at 32°F) = -1,813-2,494*Conc-0,02962*Conc^2+0,000543*Conc.^3; 
with the decimal numbers being $a_0$ to $a_3$.

Comment: @Capt.Krusty. You do not answer my questions.

Comment: I'm sorry. I added a diagramm I am building on. 
Could you elaborate with an example how to start with number/data?

Comment: @Capt.Krusty. I told you to work at constant concentration. Give me the results of $z_y$ for a few $y$.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot list them beatifully in the coomments. See edit in question.